# QML global variable

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to expose a global variable from C++ to QML, but I'm not able to make it accessible for all QML files.

I'm trying to add my context property to the `QQmlEngine` root context because, according to the documentation:

#### QQmlEngine documentation:

> QQmlContext * QQmlEngine::rootContext() const Returns the engine's
>   root context.
>
> The root context is automatically created by the QQmlEngine. Data that
>   should be available to all QML component instances instantiated by the
>   engine should be put in the root context.
>
> Additional data that should only be available to a subset of component
>   instances should be added to sub-contexts parented to the root
>   context.

It's supposed that this property should be available for all the QML files. I'm doing it like that:

#### MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      engine(new QQmlEngine(parent)),
      window(NULL)
{
    // Set global properties
    this->setIndependentResolutionScale();

    // Load the QML file
    QQmlComponent component(this->engine, QUrl("qrc:/qml/MainWindow.qml"));
    this->window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(component.create());
    this->engine->setIncubationController(this->window->incubationController());
}

void MainWindow::setIndependentResolutionScale()
{
    // In a standard resolution laptop screen->logicalDotsPerInch() is 72
    QScreen *screen = qApp->screens().at(0);
    qreal u = 72.0/screen->logicalDotsPerInch();

    this->engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("u", u);
}
```

I haven't got problems if I use this property in `MainWindow.qml` but, if I try to use it in other QML file I get a `ReferenceError: u is not defined`.

Why is this error caused? Is it because `QQmlEngine` is not unique? Is there another way to create a global variable?

I'm using Qt 5.2

Comment: Are you sure that you add context property before you show window?

Comment: Yes, the property works in that window, but not in the other QML files of the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783008/share-an-object-between-qml-files/26783146#26783146

Comment: Temporary variable won't release after funcation invoked?