# call QML function from C++ with another QML object as parameter

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML file `Dialog.qml` which is `ApplicationWindow` and `Tab.qml` which is `Item`. There are `TabView` in `Dialog.qml` which tabs is formed from `Tab.qml`. I want to create `Tab.qml` in `Qt`, connect its signals to classes in `Qt` and add that tab to `Dialog`. Here is relevant part of code:

```
//Tab.qml
Item {
    id: tb
    anchors.fill: parent
    //...here is signals and controls like RadioButtons and TextFields
}

//Dialog.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: "settings"
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    //...
    function addTabfromCpp(tab){
        frame.addTab("from c++", tab);
    }
    TabView {
        id:frame
        //...
    }
}
```

I know how to call `QML` functions from `Qt` when function parameters are primitive types(via `QVariant`). But how to call function when its parameter is `QQuickWindow` or other and it is not possible to create `QVariant` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass QML object ids as function parameters just fine. In C++ those work as `QObject *`. Also, besides ids you can use the `parent` property, or `children[indexOfChild]`. Note that you don't pass the actual objects, since that would require invoking a copy constructor, and copying is disabled for all `QObject` derived classes, it is passed by reference, which works in JS with `var` and in C++ with `QObject*`. In a similar fashion, you can use `QObject*` to pass objects to QML. Additionally, you might want to add your custom types to the Qt metatypes with `qRegisterMetaType()` or `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, which will give you autocomplete for that type in QML.

In order to expose C++ functions in the QML context, you need to make those functions either slots or `Q_INVOKABLE` of a `QObject` derived class, instantiate the class and use `setContextProperty()` to expose it to QML.

Or alternatively, you can register that object to the QML engine so you can instantiate it, you can even share the same data across multiple instances of that object by following [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783008/share-an-object-between-qml-files/26783146#26783146)

EDIT: OK, try this one:

QML:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    objectName: "blah"
    //...
    function foo(obj) { console.log(obj) }
}
```

CPP:

```
QObject * root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(root, "foo", Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(root)));
```

and output is

```
qml: ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_11_QML_12(0x4121e70, "blah")
```

Seems you have to pass it as a `Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(QObject*)`

However, `TabView.addTab()` expects not an object (which is an instance of a `Component`) but a component, i.e. a prototype for an object.

One way you can do that is:

```
QObject * root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
QQmlComponent comp(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/Test.qml"));
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(root, "addTab", Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(&comp)));
```

Comment: here is slot for button. After button is clicked new Tab should be added
    void MainWindow::buttonClicked(){
        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///Tab.qml")));
        QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(window, "addTabfromCpp",
            Q_ARG(QObject*, topLevel));}   
However it gives an error  **QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method Dialog_QMLTYPE_57::addTabfromCpp(QObject*)**

Comment: thanks, now it pass QObject* to QML. However the program gives runtime error: ** Cannot assign QObject* to QQmlComponent* ** in QML function **addTabfromCpp(tab){ frame.addTab ("from c++", tab);}**

Comment: In that function I add parameter(Item) to **TabView** (it was given in the body of the question).